# Disabling area transitions in practice mode - Injustice 2

Tags: injustice-2

I'm learning a combo which has a tendency to push the opponent into a corner and one of the linking moves is the area transition, so after 2-3 combos I have to wait for the cutscene.

Any way around that?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use an arena with no area transitions. Duh.